# How to slide ads in/out using admob in Android

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to show ads in an Android app I am developing. I have integrated with admob sdk and successfully seeing ads. But I don't want the ads to show always. I want them to slide out stay there for a few seconds and hide and start showing again in a cycle. I tried using the Handler with a thread but the call `adView.setVisibilty(View.GONE)` never really did anything .

Does anyone know how to slide the ads in and out at regular intervals

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055885/admob-in-android-how-to-make-it-appear-and-disappear